# My build.gradle not compatible with error in line 22

Tags: android, reactjs, build, android-gradle-plugin, native

I generated my key with keytool and pasted it into the android / app folder, but running the command ./gradlew assembleRelease returns the error:

➜ android git: (master) / ./gradlew assembleRelease

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Onde:
  Build file '/Volumes/Projects/Apps/calculator/android/build.gradle' line: 22

My build.gradle is different from the documentation, attached I show my build.gradle

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
android { // line 22
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

Build file '/Volumes/Projetos/Apps/calculator/android/build.gradle' line: 22

Comment: which one is the problemematic line 22?

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines to your gradle.properties file in /android folder

```
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE=youkeystorefilenamehere.keystore
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS=yourkeyalias
MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD=yourstorepassword
MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD=yourkeypassword
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `android` block in the top-level file.
Move it inside the `module/build.gradle` file.

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

android {
  ....


}
```